# Adressing UILabel in UIView with viewwithtag not working

Tags: ios, uilabel, viewwithtag

I have got a **DetailViewController** with a **UIView** (white background). 
Inside this UIView I have got a couple of labels which I want to adress dynamically. So I decided to use viewWithTag

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    UILabel *l = (UILabel*)[_bgresult viewWithTag:6];
    l.text = @"TEST";
```

But the text never appears. What do I wrong?

Comment: You should probably investigate using `IBOutlet`s..

Comment: where are you calling the update to the label's text? if you put in a breakpoint just after calling `viewWithTag:` is your `UILabel` non-nil?

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%@",[_bgresult viewWithTag:6]);` and what is the result you are getting ?

Comment: @IanMacDonald: Yes but I want to go through the labels in a for loop like this: `for (int i=0; i<[result count]; i++) {UILabel *l = (UILabel*)[_bgresult viewWithTag:6+i]; l.text = [result objectAtIndex:i];
    }`

Comment: @MidhunMP yes it's (null), but I don't know why?

Comment: @Raphael: First check you set the tag for that label, second check whether you connected the outlet for `_bgresult`

Answer (score 1):

I put the code into 
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
and now it works. 
Nevertheless thanks for your help!